# Can not find jest in subpackage of yarn workspace

Tags: typescript, jestjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to refactor a Typescript project to monorepo with multiple packages (with yarn workspaces). In one of the packages (`packages/compiler`) I have jest installed, and have several tests. They worked before, but after refactoring I get the following error message:

> Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a
>
> test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`

I can't seem to figure out how to get jest to work.

I have jest installed "locally" in the package with all the tests. But if I check `node_modules/` after a `yarn install`, I can only see a `.bin` directory in `packages/compiler/node_modules`, and I can see (ts-)jest installed in the "root" `node_modules`. I think that I need to make sure that jest is installed in the node_modules of my packages (`packages/compiler/node_modules`) instead of in the root. But I can't seem to work out how to do that (the `nohoist` option in the root package.json doesn't work).

So my question is how do I get jest to work in my subpackage?

The root `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "pannenkoekjs",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.18.4"
  }
}
```

The `package.json` in `packages/compiler`:

```
{
  "name": "@pannenkoekjs/compiler",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
  }
}
```

And the `jest.config.js` in `packages/compiler`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently the error wasn't about it not finding jest, but the type definitions. I have `@types/jest` installed, but it is installed in de "root" node_modules. And in my `tsconfig.json` in `packages/compiler` I had te following:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./src/@types",
]
```

In other words; it was looking for type definitions in the local node_modules of that package (so `packages/compiler/node_modules`), while jest's type definitions were installed in the root. So adding that to the typeRoots fixed my issue:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "../../node_modules/@types",
    "./src/@types",
]
```

Comment: but what if I'm using package also as git submodule?. The explicit typeroot definition seems dirty. why cannot yarn workspace detect itself?

Comment: @softmashmallow Indeed... the explicit typeroot definition isn't great. It'll do for now (for my use case) but check out adding the "nohoist" config in the project root package.json for exluding particular packages from hoisting. You might get that to work better.